# How to compare a session variable to a row in a table

Tags: php

I have the following code to display posts in a forum discussion.

I would like the person who posted a reaction to see two buttons:

- A delete button
- An edit button

I can't seem to find a way to connect the user session to the userid in the forumberichten table. Is there anyone who can help me with this? I've tried a lot of things, but I keep getting the buttons on all the posts.

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
}

$user = $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
    $user = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['user']);
}

$sql="SELECT forumberichten.bericht_id,forumberichten.discussieid,forumberichten.userid,forumberichten.omschrijving,forumberichten.datum, forumberichten.active,users.userid,users.username,users.userimage FROM forumberichten,users WHERE forumberichten.userid=users.userid AND forumberichten.active='yes' AND forumberichten.discussieid='".$id."' ORDER BY discussieid DESC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >=1) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
            <br><table width='450' border='0'>
            <tr><td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan='5' bgcolor='#1E1E1E'><a href='user.php? id=" . $row['userid'] . "'</a> ".$row["username"]."</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan='5' bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>
        ";

        if ($row["userimage"] == '') {
            echo "
                <a href='user.php? id=" . $row['userid'] . "'</a>
                <img src='Images/users/nopicture.png' alt='nopicture'  class='user-imagelarge' title='".$row['username']."''>
                </a>
            ";
        } else {
            echo "
                <a href='user.php? id=" . $row['userid'] . "'</a>
                <img src='Images/users/".$row['userimage']."' class='user-imagelarge' title='".$row['username']."''>
                </a>
            ";
        }
        echo "
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan='5' bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>".$row['omschrijving']."</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>
        ";

        echo date("d-m-y H:i",strtotime($row["datum"]));"</td>";

        // HERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO SO ONLY THE POSTER OF THIS MESSAGE CAN SEE THE FOLLOWING BUTTONS:
        echo "
            <td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'><a href='forumberichtbewerk.php? id=" . $row['bericht_id'] . "' target='_blank'>
            <input type='image'  src='Images/Icons/penorange.png' width='15' height='15'></a></td>
            <td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'><a href='forumberichtdelete.php? id=" . $row['bericht_id'] . "'><input type='image' class='backgroundgreyfotoos' src='Images/Icons/crossorangebutton.png' width='15' height='15' border='0' ></a></td>
            <td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'></td>
            <td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor='#1E1E1E'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan='5' bgcolor='#1E1E1E'><img src='Images/lijntransparant.png' width='570' height='2'></td>
            <td><img src='Images/lijntransparant.png' width='35' height='2'></td></tr>
            </table>
        ";       
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if ($row['userid'] == $_SESSION['SESS_USERID']) { showButton(); }`?

Comment: you have an error at the end of the line `echo date("d-m-y H:i" ...`

Comment: Could you please tell me the error? It is working fine the way it is ,but if it can be improved that would be so much better.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The { showButton(); } works but the id inside the href isn't passed on. I'm not familiar with functions. How do I pass on the id=" . $row['bericht_id'] . "'?

Comment: Is solved by not using the function.